# Issue with printing without creating newline in Python when running from terminal

Tags: python, pycharm

I am just starting up with Python and was trying to figure out how to print the contents of a list of items without getting a newline for each new item printed. I've looked around on the web for solutions, one of which being replacing print(x) with print(x, end="") when printing an item x. My simple code is as follows:

```py
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for x in list:
    print(x, end="")
```

I'm of course expecting the simple output of

```py
12345
```

which I get when i run the script in PyCharm, but when I try to run the code from the terminal I get the error message:

```
 print(x, end="")
             ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this happening? I am running Python 3.6 by the way.

Comment: Try running from terminal with `python3`

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is available only in Python3. You need to check your Python version again because it has to work as you see below:

```
>>> python test.py 
  File "test.py", line 4
    print(x, end="")
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python3 test.py 
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

print(*a,sep='')
```

output

```
12345
```